Why a component is wrapped by forwardRef , storybook <Controls /> table is rendered incomplete?
I have a button react component and it defined as a forwardRef component:
const Button = forwardRef<HTMLElement, ButtonProps>((props, ref) => {
    const { type, children, tagName, variant, color, size = "md", disabled, ...otherProps } = props;
    const Component: ElementType = (tagName || (type ? "button" : "span")) as ElementType;
    const getCenterIconSpaces = () => {
        if (size === "xs") {
            return "px-2xs py-2xs";
        } else if (size === "sm") {
            return "px-xs py-xs";
        } else if (size === "md") {
            return "px-sm py-sm";
        } else if (size === "lg") {
            return "px-md py-sm";
        } else if (size === "xl") {
            return "px-xl py-xl";
        } else {
            return "px-sm py-sm";
        }
    };
    const componentClasses = (): string =>
        getClassNames(
            classNames.btn,
            variant && color && classNames[`btn-${variant}-${color}`],
            variant && !color && classNames[`btn-${variant}-primary`],
            !variant && color && classNames[`btn-${color}`],
            size && classNames[`btn-${size}`],
            disabled && classNames["btn-disabled"],
            
            otherProps.className && otherProps.className
        );

    return (
        <Component {...otherProps} ref={ref} className={componentClasses()} type={type}>
                {children}
        </Component>
    );
});

Button.displayName = "x-button";
export default Button;

The button component also has the following interface:
export interface ButtonProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
    tagName?: "button" | "span" | "a";
    children?: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] | string;
    href?: string;
    target?: HTMLAttributeAnchorTarget;
    color?: "basic" | "primary" | "red" | "green" | "orange";
    variant?: "outline" | "text";
    size?: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl";
    type?: "button" | "submit" | "reset";
    disabled?: boolean;
}


For the above component., I have written the following story :
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import { Button, ButtonX } from "@lib/components/Button/Button";
import { ComponentProps } from "react";
import { ButtonProps } from "@lib/components/Button/props.interfaces";


const meta = {
    title: "Button",
    component: Button,
    args: {
        children: "buy"
    }
} satisfies Meta;

export default meta;

type StoryX = StoryObj<typeof Button>;

export const Default: StoryX = {
    render: (args) => <Button {...args}>{args.children}</Button>
};

When i run the command npm run storybook the displayed args in the control section of panel , just includes the children. But when i write the button component without forwardRef, It displays all of the component props.
How can i fix this problem without changing the component structure? And how can describe this behaviour of storybook?
